# probability of joint PDF

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, random-variables

[image]

I found $k = 4$ and yes, the are independent.

But for the last one I know how to find the probability if they are like $x$  from $0$ to a number and $y$ from $0$ to a number so the limit of double integration is clear.

But here we need $x+y$ less than $1$ at the same time! How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

For the last part you just need to set the limits of integration correctly. The limits for $X$ ($0$ to $1$) are all the $X$ values for which $X+Y\lt 1$ is possible. Then, for $Y$, we treat $X$ as a constant between $0$ and $1$ and the limits of integration for $Y$ should cover all possible values for $Y$ that satisfy $X+Y\lt 1$. So,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X+Y\lt 1) &=& \int_{x=0}^{1}{\int_{y=0}^{1-x}{4xy\;dy\;dx}} \\
&=& \int_{x=0}^{1}{\left[2xy^2\right]_{y=0}^{1-x}\;dx} \\
&=& \int_{x=0}^{1}{2x(1-x)^2\;dx} \\
&=& \left[x^4/2-4x^3/3+x^2\right]_{0}^{1} \\
&=& 1/6.
\end{eqnarray*}